# AngularJS: How to get the previous url and replace its parameters?

Tags: angularjs, browser-history, routeparams

I am using angular [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) in my application to change the urls. I want to get the previous url and replace some of its route parameters.

```
$routeProvider.when("/editUser/:userId", {
  templateUrl: "app/user/userEdit.html", 
  controller: "UserCtrl"
});
```

For example, if my previous url is the above one, I want to change it's parameter `userId` into something else. (previous url: `/editUser/1`, I want to change it to: `/editUser/2`)

Can I do something like that using AngularJS?

Comment: How should the application decide to go to `/editUser/2` as opposed to `/editUser/3` or `/editUser/1`? What should trigger this action?... Browser back button... or user interaction within the web page?

Comment: @MatthewCawley the  answer for ur question - user interaction within the web page

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular route change events for this purpose, such as

```
$routeChangeStart, $routeChangeSuccess, $routeChangeError, $routeUpdate
```

Here is an example

```
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        console.log("Next - "  + next.$$route.originalPath);
        console.log("Current - "  + current.$$route.originalPath);
    });
```

You can store this in any scope values.